# internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:800 throw err

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, yarnpkg, ts-node

Executed yarn install in my project folder and got below error.

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:800
throw err;
^
Error: Cannot find module 'ts-node/register'
Require stack:
- internal/preload
?[90m    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:797
:15)?[39m
?[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:27)?[39m
?[90m    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:852:19)?[39m
?[90m    at Module._preloadModules (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1147:12)?[39m
?[90m    at loadPreloadModules (internal/bootstrap/pre_execution.js:443:5)?[39m
?[90m    at prepareMainThreadExecution (internal/bootstrap/pre_execution.js:62:3
)?[39m
?[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:7:1?[39m {
code: ?[32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'?[39m,
requireStack: [ ?[32m'internal/preload'?[39m ]
}
```

Removed node_module, yarn.lock and node-cache. But no success.

This error is not project specific. If i run yarn, node or npm anywhere in my system I'm getting above error. Is my node and yarn package corrupted?

Comment: Have you installed the dependencies ? `npm install` if you have the dependency in your package.json, or `npm install ts-node` if not

Comment: @Seblor I have ts-node as my dev-dependency. i added moment in my package and to install i run yarn install. Then it gave above error.Before running yarn install everything was working fine.

Comment: I'm not getting how it corrupted  my entire system.. This issue is now not project specific.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling node ? I suggest using [`nvm`](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) for managing node installs

Comment: Yes, reinstalled both node and yarn.

Comment: What about installing an other version ?

Comment: Installed latest version node 12.16 and yarn 1.22.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208188/discussion-between-himanshu-shekhar-and-seblor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved Issue by checking NODE_OPTIONS

Run `echo %NODE_OPTIONS%` and got `ts-node/register`.

So, to remove ts-node/register run `setx NODE_OPTIONS ""`

After this node,npm and yarn are working properly.

Comment: Thanks, for me - upgrading latest node v fixes the issue

Answer (score 0):

Try following command:

Step 1 : `remove node_modules  and files and package-lock.json`

Then run following command to install dependencies:

Step 2: `$ rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json && npm install && npm start`

Finally, run your package by following command:

`npm start`

Comment: This issue is not project specific. I tried all things which you mentioned in your answer. I resolved this issue and also provided the solution. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60320834/7026966

Comment: +1 in my case it was project specific and this fix helped me.  my issue occurred after Windows 10 updates on insider build on 3/22/21

Answer (score 0):

For me it was showing
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1147
I was trying to run node cmd in internal folder where module was not installed.
It worked for me when I run the cmd from the folder where my index.js file was saved.